# theming price format in drupal ubercart

Tags: drupal-theming, ubercart

What I am trying to achieve is to theme the price format the following way. I only want to remove the decimals when they are 00.

For example €5,00 should be €5, but €5,50 should remain the same, not €5,5.
I [found a forum](http://drupal.org/node/636382#comment-5159448) about this problem but I dont know how to implement it, especially overriding `theme_uc_product_price()` as suggested [here](http://drupal.org/node/625214).

Answer (score 0):

Those links suggest using either the Computed Field Module or a Preprocess function but it would be simple with a bit of JQuery:

Let's say you have a div like so:

```
<div class="field-price">€ 5,00</div>
```

You could then target that element with a replace:

```
$('.field-price:contains(",00")').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/00/g, '');
});​
```

I wrote a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JySHQ/1/

Note please indicate what version of Drupal you have and then I give give you some hints as how to implement as Javascript is different in Drupal 6 vs. Drupal 7

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I use drupal 6. Your example looks really useful. I am concerned about users without javascript as well because believe it or not, according analytics almost 30%of my visitors don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: This seems like a cosmetic change more than anything so since it's Javascript, it will degrade gracefully and simply show the trailing zeros. I looked at the other solutions in your links and they seemed fairly kludgy to implement so I came up with the Jquery. If you need it for Drupal 6, let me know and I'll put some code here as well.

Comment: If you would be so kind I would ask for a code overriding theme_uc_product_price() as suggested by maintainer of the project ubercart. I would say that this code will be of great use for many european shop owners who don§t need to display trailing zeroes. Thank you very much.